# active scroll on one page responsive

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

anyone know how i can add a scroll active class on one page website ? 
this is my html :

```
<div class="header-container">

        <a href="#ancla1"><div class="company-name">zxx<span>nkxxx.</span></div></a>
       <div id="tendina" class="block-menu">

           <nav class="nav-collapse closed">

                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#ancla1">HOME</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#ancla4">WORKS</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                     <a href="#ancla6">CONTACT</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>


        </div>


        <div class="menu-select">
            <nav>
                <ol class="contentMenu">

                      <li>
                        <a href="#ancla1"><div class="menubtn">
                            <div class="contentbtn">home</div>
                        </div></a>
                    </li>


                    <li>
                        <a href="#ancla4"><div class="menubtn">
                            <div class="contentbtn">works</div>
                        </div></a>
                    </li>

                      <li>
                        <a href="#ancla6"><div class="menubtn">
                            <div class="contentbtn">contact</div>
                        </div></a>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- end header-->
```

and this is my active class :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.contentbtn').first().addClass('attivo');
    $('.portfolio-btn').first().addClass('attivo');

      var navigation = responsiveNav(".nav-collapse", {
        animate: true,        // Boolean: Use CSS3 transitions, true or false
        transition: 250,      // Integer: Speed of the transition, in milliseconds
        label: "Menu",        // String: Label for the navigation toggle
        insert: "after",      // String: Insert the toggle before or after the navigation
        customToggle: "",     // Selector: Specify the ID of a custom toggle
        openPos: "relative",  // String: Position of the opened nav, relative or static
        jsClass: "js",        // String: 'JS enabled' class which is added to <html> el
        init: function(){},   // Function: Init callback
        open: function(){},   // Function: Open callback
        close: function(){}   // Function: Close callback
      });

    //active state  
    $(function() {
        $('.contentbtn').click(function(e) {

            var $this = $(this);
            $('.contentbtn').removeClass('attivo');
            $this.addClass('attivo');

        });
        $('.portfolio-btn').click(function(e) {

            var $this = $(this);
            $('.portfolio-btn').removeClass('attivo');
            $this.addClass('attivo');

        });



    });

});
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what it is you're asking.  Could you put together a working example of what you'd like help with? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is a particularly good place to get a working example up that others can see/interact with.